# Passing values with load() in URL string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am loading a page in to a parent page using the load() function but I am also passing values in a URL string of the loaded page.

It's pretty straight forward; where I am having an issue is on the page that that is loaded the windows.location function only sees the parent url.

How can I or what can I use to see the loaded URL string instead of the parents URL string?

code example of page being loaded in to parent page:

```
$('.MEDHISTRODATA').load('MedicalHistoryInit.html?AGE='+a+'&DOE='+d+'&PATIENTID='+p);
```

I am using this function to extract the URL params from the URL string:

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam){
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++){
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam){
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a URL parameter by name, you can also use RegExp:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' 
                            + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) || 
                            [, ""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || 
                            null
}
```

So, to call it on load:

```
window.onload = function init() {
    var param_age = getURLParameter('AGE');
}
```

Comment: Your code works however I am still having the same issue local.search only searches the parent URL